# Multiple elements with same class make jquery click event to fire multiple times

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I display user comments. Each comment is one `div` and each `div` has `<a>` tag with class '`commentLikeLink`'. I bind jquery click event to '`commentLikeLink`' class but If I have 10 comments and click on one like button I get event fired 10 times. 
I know that this happen's because I have same class multiple times. But How to stop this?
Here's the code:

```
...
<div class="commentBox"">
...
@Html.ActionLink(likeText, "LikeComment", "Comment", null, new { id = Model.CommentId, @class = "commentLikeLink" })    
...
```

Event code:

```
$(function () {
            $('.commentLikeLink').click(function (event) {
                var commentId = event.target.id;

                $.ajax({
                    url: this.href,
                    type: 'POST',                    
                    data: { commentId: commentId },
                    context: this,
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.msg == '1') {
                            $(this).text('Dislike');
                        }
                        else if(result.msg == '2') {
                            $(this).text('Like');
                        }

                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you show your final source output?

Comment: how do you know it fires 10 times ?

Comment: Just because you have ten elements on the page with the same class and have bound a click event to elements of that class does not mean that when one of them is actually clicked all ten get click events.

Comment: @Mike Brant this is the output: <a class="commentLikeLink" href="/app/Comment/LikeComment" id="205">Like</a>

Comment: @Shyju because it call controller action 10 times.

Comment: @1110: It wont .check this http://jsfiddle.net/2QJsJ/2/

Comment: is that javascript code included each time a comment is loaded?

Comment: @MrOBrian: I think that could be the problem

Comment: @MrOBrian: yes that was the problem. I have a view that render all comments in a for loop. And I put this event handler in that loop. I put handler in parent view so it works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this happen before when i accidently included the same .click script function multiple times in the page. Make sure your javascript is only included once

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't be getting 10 clicks. You can bind the click event to the class, but the context in which the event is fired is the individual element, so if you had some markup that looked like this:

```
<p>
    <a href="#" class="clickItem">Liked?</a>
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="clickItem">Liked?</a>
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="clickItem">Liked?</a>
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="clickItem">Liked?</a>
</p>
```

Then this would work, setting the link text to "Liked!" as each one is clicked:

```
$(document).on("click", ".clickItem", function (ev) {
    $(this).text("Liked!");
});
```

Have you debugged the code? Are you sure you're getting 10 clicks all at once?

Answer (score 4):

yes binding the click event to the class is a better solution, but it can actually get fired multiple times if you use it on the item it self or the class it self !

so instead of having this : `$('.commentLikeLink').click(function (event) {`//do things here }

you should do this and it will only fire once :

```
$(document).on("click", ".commentLikeLink", function (ev) {
    //do things here
});
```